# Connect 3 photos by line layout as path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I've tried to build this layout as the path from 3 peoples for representing sender transporter and receiver of a pack:
[Layout I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNNRF.png)

But I can't reach it. My result is...bad

[my bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTYQX.png)

This is my layout code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rlMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#76e6e6e6"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:divider="@drawable/contact_divider"
    android:layout_margin="1dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtvRichiestaID"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_centerVertical="false"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="CODICE RICHIESTA"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

<!-- box blue -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum=""
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_celeste"
        >




        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_mittente"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_arrotondato_mittente"
           android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgMittente"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chatplaceholder" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nomeMittente"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome\n Mittente"/>


        </LinearLayout>

<!--  boxer yellow --->


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_trasportatore"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_arrotondato_trasportatore"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTrasportatore"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chatplaceholder" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nomeTrasportatore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome\n Trasportatore"/>
            </LinearLayout>





        </LinearLayout>

<!--  boxer green --->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/box_destinatario"

            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/box_arrotondato_destinatario"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgDestinatario"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/account_photo_dim"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/chatplaceholder" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nomeDestinatario"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:ellipsize="middle"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nome\n Destinatario"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Can someone helps me? 
This is for representing a sending pack to others by the transporter.
Thanks for any helps! :)

Comment: I recommend you to use the constraint layout
You can easily connect your ImageView with Horizontal divider line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bellow is your answer, I just replace ImageView with your CircularImageView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:id="@+id/mImgSender"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetest"
        app:civ_border_width="10dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mTVSenderName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        android:text="Name Sen"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mViewDiv1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/mImgSender"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/mImgSender"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:layout_height="15dp" />


    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        app:civ_border_width="10dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetest"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mTVReceiverName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        android:text="Name Rec"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/mImgTrans"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mImgSender"
        android:src="@drawable/imagetest"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/mImgSender"
        app:civ_border_width="10dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mImgReceiver"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mTVTransName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mImgTrans"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/mImgTrans"
        android:text="Name Trans"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mImgTrans"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, your code is very clear and nice! Thanks @DhavalSolanki! But how can I create a halo around the image?

Comment: If it is helpful then please acpt and up--Vote.

Comment: No problem, Thanks for acpt.

Comment: Ehm @Dhaval Solanki ehm I've asked below your answer how to make an halo and how can I insert on top of all circles with with matching parent and text "Chat:" and below the names a layout that contains other informations? Thnks

Comment: Yes. I've replace with circleimage because image must be circled...

Comment: I suggest use bellow library which will give you lot of property like border or other thing https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: You can replace that view with above ImageView and set border.

Comment: What is the problem with that? is there any exception?

Comment: No I can't see the border. Sorry for not answered... I was busy

Comment: Okay, give me some time I will get back to you.

Comment: Hi, @CristianCapannini I added result or answer with your requirement using this library https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refer_friend"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refer_friend"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <View
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="50dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_refer_friend"/>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I've accepted other answer. cannot accept two answer and not click up button sorry :(